# Increment variable number in PHP wp

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to create a variable that holds value incremented by 7
and then I need to assign it to `$_POST` so I can insert the value in db

```
$arr = array(1, 8, 15...);
$marker_name = wp_specialchars($_POST['marker_name']);  + $arr; //somehow attach it

if(isset($_POST['attach'])) {
   $rows_affected_two = $wpdb->insert( $table_add_two, array('marker_name' => $marker_name + $arr) );
}
```

I need to insert every input into db generated by js that holds the name incremented by 7.
so every submit will be inserted in db
marker_name1
marker_name8
marker_name15
...
 Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add it inside a [`while`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php) loop, something like this:

```
$i = 0;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) and $i < $nums_row) {  
    echo '<th align="left" class="cell'.$i++.'"><b>'. $row['languages'] .'</b></th>';
}

echo '<th align="left">Action</th></tr></thead>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to strip numbers from the end of marker_name first:

```
$arr = array(1, 8, 15...);
$marker_name = preg_replace("/d+$/", "", wp_specialchars($_POST['marker_name']));
$marker_name .= $arr[0];


if(isset($_POST['attach'])) {
   $rows_affected_two = $wpdb->insert( $table_add_two, array('marker_name' => $marker_name) );
}
```

Comment: but I need those numbers there! With JS I populate new input fields with this unique numbers. It's ok, it won't work. I tried it manually to create all variables. It didn't work. I have decided for different solution to use. Thanks for your time though!